# from facebook, i want to fetch Hometown details . from it i want to saparate city,state, country

Tags: php, facebook

From facebook, i want to fetch Hometown details . from it i want to separate city,state, country. These fields are separated by comma. so i can split them by comma.

my problem is: as soon  i enter city name in hometown field of facebook, it is giving combination of city,state and country.
but sometime it is giving combination of city and country
so, when i split this string by comma, how to i know that second element is state or country.

I can do one thing, i can check the length of array, if it has three filed then it has city/state/county. else city/county.

Is this ture? can it have more files.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just query the FQL [`user`](http://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/fql/user/) table:

```
SELECT hometown_location FROM user WHERE uid=me()
```

This would return something like:

```
[
  {
    "hometown_location": {
      "city": "xxxxx",
      "state": "xxxxx",
      "country": "xxxx",
      "zip": "xxxxx",
      "id": xxxx,
      "name": "xxx, xxx, xxxxx"
    }
  }
]
```

Of course some of the fields will be empty if the user didn't set them. (result set returned using the [fql.query test console](http://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/rest/fql.query/))